# problem with Apache / Passenger - 500 error - where to look?

Tags: apache-2.2, phusion-passenger, 500-error

I installed passenger with rails 1.9.2 in a rvm but I'm getting errors when trying to load anything. (We're sorry but something went wrong). I'm able to load a txt file out of the public directory.

It looks like passenger is working:

```
jon@ve:~$ apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
Loaded Modules:
 ...
passenger_module (shared)
Syntax OK
jon@ve:~$
```

In the top level apache error log, I see the non-descript:

```
 cache: [GET /jt] miss
 [Tue Sep 27 13:36:50 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

The vhost container is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName domain.com
   ServerAlias www.domain.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/testapp/public
</VirtualHost>
```

What would be the next place to look?

Comment: Add a `ErrorLog` directive for your virtual host, reprodure this error and take a look at this.